# No output when detecting change in variable C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# (and coding in general) and trying to do a basic exercise where I print a set of variables, swap the variables, and then print the new variables. I thought it would be fun to try and have the concatenated string that prints the variables update on its own when the variables change but have hit a wall trying to do this.

```
public class Exercise1
{



    public static double num1 = 3;
    public static double num2 = 2;

    public static string readable;

    public static double Num1{
        get { return num1;}
        set {
            readable = num1 + ", " + num2;
        }
    }


    public static void Main( )
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(readable);

        num1 = 2;
        num2 = 3;

        System.Console.WriteLine(readable);

    }

}
```

The idea was to check for a change in `num1` and then update `readable` if there is one, but that doesn't seem to be working as there's no output when I do this.

EDIT: Also, is there a way to get both `num1` and `num2`? Do I need to create a tuple for them?

Comment: You never use the Num1 property.  This is not what a property should be used for.  Add a method, name it UpdateReadable() and you'll automatically write correct code.

Comment: Automatic UI updates on changes are not a basic thematic. It is a advanced UI topic. If you need a updated value for readable, you have to recreate it from scratch. Also that whole thing about creating readable in the setter? Terribly bad. It does not help that you are doing the classical msitake and access the backing Field of the property, rather then the property and thus it's setter. it is common practice to add a underscore as prefix to the backing field to avoid those misshaps.

Comment: I don't think you don't need to create multiple variables.I have created another sample. May be that also will help you.

Comment: This makes sense now. I wasn't aware that what I was writing was a property or how it worked - I thought it was linking Num1 and num1. I've been trying to learn just by looking through code snippets and testing things so that can lead to confusion. Originally I had written a property for readable, but switched it to Num1 when it wasn't working. This clarifies a lot. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Exercise1
{



    public static double num1 = 3;
    public static double num2 = 2;

    public static string readable
    {
      get { return num1 + ", " + num2;}
    };

    public static void Main( )
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(readable);

        num1 = 2;
        num2 = 3;

        System.Console.WriteLine(readable);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you want is to update readable automatically whenever num1 is updated. You have followed the right approach by using a property however you need to do it slightly differently. First is you have to update the property rather than the variable directly and secondly update the variables value through the property. You can achieve this by

```
set{
   num1=value;
   readable = num1 + ", " + num2;
}
```

Moreover in your code use `Num1 = 2` instead of `num1=2`. And if you want to do this on both variables you can have another property for num2

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you don't need a separate variable like **num1** and **num2** . Look at the below sample code , I have create **Num1** as just read only property.Means, you can't set any value in to it. Instead you can use this property as to read the concatenated string.

```
using System;

public class Exercise1
{

    public static double num = 3;

    public static string readable;

    public static string Num1
    {
        get
        {
             readable = readable + "," +num;
             return readable.TrimStart(',');
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Num1);
        num = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(Num1);
        num = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(Num1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Whenever you change the value of **num** and console the output , you will get the new readable string by appending the new value.

See the output

[image]